# PHP rename an uploaded file destroys its extension

Tags: php

In my upload file script, I need to change the uploaded file name (they're all images) to a combination of the userId of the user uploading the file + a few other things.

I have everything working fine, but the only problem is when I use `move_uploaded_file` and specify a new file name there, I get a file with the new name, but without the extension.

Without having to write any more code for the extension, can I get the file name there with it's new name and original extension?

I currently do:

```
$tempFile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$newName = 'userId'.time() 

if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$root.'/images/'.$userId.'/'.$newName)) {

}
```

but end with this...

[image]

This is the same uploaded file, but with no extension. If I manually change the extension, I can see the image there.

Comment: Because you set the new filename with `$newName = 'userId'.time() `, why are you surprised that it has that name?

Comment: You need to add the extension with your new file name.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to first, extract the original extension from the original file name and then add it to your $newname variable.

The name needs to have the extension in it, there is no way around that, if you know what the extension will always be, you cvan

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$tempFile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$file = explode('.', $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);

$newName = 'userId'.time().'.'.$file[count($file)-1]; 

if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$root.'/images/'.$userId.'/'.$newName)) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
$tempFile = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
$newName = 'userId'.time() . "." . substr($_FILES['file']['name'], strpos('.'), strlen($_FILES['file']['name']));

if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$root.'/images/'.$userId.'/'.$newName)) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the new filename with `$newName = 'userId'.time()`, why are you surprised that it has that name?

To preserve the original extension, first you need to find it, then add it to the new filename. You can use Fileinfo PHP extension to guess the file extension:

```
$finfo    = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $tempFile);
finfo_close($finfo);

// Set file extension & exif data, if any
$exif = array();
switch ($mimeType) {
    case 'image/png':
        $fileExtension = 'png';

        break;
    case 'image/gif':
        $fileExtension = 'gif';
        break;

    case 'image/jpg':
    case 'image/jpeg':
        $fileExtension = 'jpg';
        break;
}
```

Then, add the extension to the new name:

```
$newName = 'userId' . time() . $fileExtension;
```